# Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

Using Spring 1.5.8.RELEASE
Jackson mapper giving the following exception.

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2018-09-04T10:44:46": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.copart.conversationapi.calldisposition.model.vo.CallLogEntity["callEndTime"])

CallEntity.java

```
@JsonProperty("callEndTime")
@Column(name = "call_end_ts")
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private Date callEndTime;
```

DAO.java

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
HashMap<String, Object> finalHashMap;
finalHashMap = convertMultiToString(requestMap);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
CallLogEntity callLogEntity = mapper.convertValue(finalHashMap, CallEntity.class);
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.9.0</version>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Change your `@JsonFormat` line to this.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
```

The format pattern you have right now expects the sting to have millisecond values - but your example string doesn't have them.

Comment: Even I pass milliseconds, then also it throws an exception.
Though milliseconds are not so important to me and this annotation worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Then you can define any format that you want like on my case - @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")