# How to format date field in JSON POST request to insert into SQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, json

I need to send a POST request with the following JSON body:

```
{
 "date": "2020-08-21"
}
```

The date field has java.sql.Date type. This request results in an error which says that it could not deserialize the given string "2020-08-21" to sql.Date. If I change the JSON by adding some kind of time:

```
{
 "date": "2020-08-21 00:00:00"
}
```

It works fine. However, I would like to be able to send only Date values without the time, and be able to convert it to sql.Date. Any ideas on how to work around this? I would really not like to use a String for date and then map it to Date. Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Don't know if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55227544/cannot-deserialize-value-of-type-java-util-date-from-string

Comment: Also, please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you a lot! The first link solved my problem. Just used a Jackson annotation for formatting.